# Can we use "super" keyword inside a class which is not derived?

Tags: java, super

Can we use super keyword in a class which is not derived. (There is such a code in Sun Certified Programmer for Java 2 , chapter 7) . Here , it is used in OfficeRoom class which is not subclass.

```
1st question example code:
Building.Java

public class Building
{
long length;
long width;

OfficeRoom [] officeRooms; // The building has number of rooms

public Building (long len,long wid,OfficeRoom [] ors)
{
length = len;
width = wid;
officeRooms = ors;
}

public long area()
{
return length * width;
}
}




OfficeRoom.java

public class OfficeRoom
{
long length;
long width;

public Office(long len,wid)
{
super(len,wid)  //What is the job of super here?? It is not inside a subclass??
}

public long area()
{
return length * width;
}
}
```

Is it possible or it is written wrong in the book?

Answer (score 4):

Everything is derived from Object, so the answer will always be *yes*, you can use super() as long as it's the first code line of the constructor. Of course it won't do anything constructive, but still, you can call it.

Comment: *"Of course it won't do anything constructive..."* Depends on where you use it. Using `super` in, say, an override of `getHashCode` could well be constructive.

Comment: I would further emphasize that it may only be the first line.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: of course, but the OP was very specific about calling `super()` in a constructor. `super.hashCode()` is a new beast entirely.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: The first part of the question is fairly open: *"1.st question: Can we use super keyword in a class which is not derived"*. Yes, the latter part does specifically relate to constructors.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'll admit, it's not a very good or specific question. I have no idea what the OP is asking, and will gladly delete this answer if he clarifies his question and a better answer appears.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: No, no -- it's a good answer and the correct one (and that's my upvote).

Comment: i have edited the question and the code.

Comment: @user1308990: please only post real code. That code makes no sense including a constructor that doesn't match the class name.

Comment: This is the real code in the book. I directly write the same code, everything is the same. Thats why i asked the question. super() is not called in a constructor body and there is no inheritance.

Comment: If your code compiles then you're transcribing it wrong. Again, you've got a constructor name that doesn't match a class name. So who knows what else you've transcribed incorrectly. At present you're only wasting our time. If you really need our help, again, please only post real compilable code (or show your compilation errors).

Answer (score 1):

1. All classes are derived except for Object, and you aren't writing that. So the question is meaningless.
2. No.